# Update JQuery UI slider depending on which part of page is shown

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, slider

I have a working JQuery UI slider which navigates the page using `window.location.hash`. The problem is I also want it to work the other way round where the slider updates depending which div is on the page as the user scrolls.

```
var slider = $('#slider');     

    $(function() {
        slider.slider({
            orientation: "vertical",
            min: 1,
            max: 14,
            value: 14,
            change: function(event, ui) {

                window.location.hash = 'eraOne';
                var value = slider.slider('value');

                if(value >= 14) {
                    window.location.hash = 'eraOne';
                }

                else if (value == 13) {
                    window.location.hash = 'eraTwo';
                }

                else if (value == 12) {
                    window.location.hash = 'eraThree';
                }

                else if (value == 11) {
                    window.location.hash = 'eraFour';
                }

                else if (value == 10) {
                    window.location.hash = 'eraFive';
                }

                else if (value == 9) {
                    window.location.hash = 'eraSix';
                }

                else if (value == 8) {
                    window.location.hash = 'eraSeven';
                }

                else if (value == 7) {
                    window.location.hash = 'eraEight';
                }

                else if (value == 6) {
                    window.location.hash = 'eraNine';
                }

                else if (value == 5) {
                    window.location.hash = 'eraTen';
                }

                else if (value == 4) {
                    window.location.hash = 'eraEleven';
                }

                else if (value == 3) {
                    window.location.hash = 'eraTwelve';
                }

                else if (value == 2) {
                    window.location.hash = 'eraThirteen';
                }

                else if (value == 1) {
                    window.location.hash = 'eraFourteen';
                };
                },
              });
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I listened to the document scroll event. On each such event, I loop over the elements to see which was the last invisible element (if their `position().top` is higher than the document scrollTop). After I find that guy, I do your inversion, then set the slider value.

Next, the slider change listener WILL FIRE. So, I have to listen to the even he is handed. If it's a manually-triggered event (from the above logic), then I simply return. IMPORTANT: If you don't return immediately, you will get caught in an infinite loop of triggers!

```js
var slider = $('#slider');
$(document).on('scroll', function() {
  var currentScrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
  var scrollToSpacer = 1;
  $('.spacer').each(function(i, v) {
    var spacer = $(v);
    if(spacer.position().top <= currentScrollTop)
      scrollToSpacer = spacer.text();
  });
  // last value assigned to scrollToSpacer is what we should set the slider value to  
  slider.slider('option', 'value', 14-parseInt(scrollToSpacer));
});
$(function() {
    slider.slider({
        orientation: "vertical",
        min: 1,
        max: 14,
        value: 14,
        change: function(event, ui) {
            if(!event.hasOwnProperty('cancelable')) // triggered programatically
              return;

            window.location.hash = 'eraOne';
            var value = slider.slider('value');

            if(value >= 14) {
                window.location.hash = 'eraOne';
            }

            else if (value == 13) {
                window.location.hash = 'eraTwo';
            }

            else if (value == 12) {
                window.location.hash = 'eraThree';
            }

            else if (value == 11) {
                window.location.hash = 'eraFour';
            }

            else if (value == 10) {
                window.location.hash = 'eraFive';
            }

            else if (value == 9) {
                window.location.hash = 'eraSix';
            }

            else if (value == 8) {
                window.location.hash = 'eraSeven';
            }

            else if (value == 7) {
                window.location.hash = 'eraEight';
            }

            else if (value == 6) {
                window.location.hash = 'eraNine';
            }

            else if (value == 5) {
                window.location.hash = 'eraTen';
            }

            else if (value == 4) {
                window.location.hash = 'eraEleven';
            }

            else if (value == 3) {
                window.location.hash = 'eraTwelve';
            }

            else if (value == 2) {
                window.location.hash = 'eraThirteen';
            }

            else if (value == 1) {
                window.location.hash = 'eraFourteen';
            };
        },
    });
});
```

```css
#slider {
  position: fixed;
  top: 3em;
  right: 1em;
}
.spacer {
  display: block;
  margin: 3em 0;
  background-color: red;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<div id="slider"></div>
<div class="spacer" id="eraOne">1</div>
<div class="spacer" id="eraTwo">2</div>
<div class="spacer" id="eraThree">3</div>
<div class="spacer" id="eraFour">4</div>
<div class="spacer" id="eraFive">5</div>
<div class="spacer" id="eraSix">6</div>
<div class="spacer" id="eraSeven">7</div>
<div class="spacer" id="eraEight">8</div>
<div class="spacer" id="eraNine">9</div>
<div class="spacer" id="eraTen">10</div>
<div class="spacer" id="eraEleven">11</div>
<div class="spacer" id="eraTwelve">12</div>
<div class="spacer" id="eraThirteen">13</div>
<div class="spacer" id="eraFourteen">14</div>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
```